# How to post pretty links in comments?

Tags: support

When posting a Q/A, I'm able to post links with the following syntax :

```
[nice link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

However, I'm not able to reproduce this effect when adding a comment. The exact same syntax gives me this :

```
[nice link][1] [1]: stackoverflow.com
```

Would you know how to post nice links in comments ?

Comment: In comments I think the best you can do is `[description](link)`

Comment: Well, this definitly works, thanks !

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169185/245360.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a flavor of Markdown.  Jeff Atwood [blogs about it in general terms](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-future-of-markdown).  There is also the [Stack Overflow Editing Help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Paul - there is also comment editing help. When you type a comment, there is a help link... Comments support a small subset of markdown, not all of it.

Comment: @Oded I've never actually *seen* that until now.

Comment: @Paul - you mean you never _noticed_ it until now ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `[Name](link)` to post a link in a comment.You can find more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) as well as by clicking the <kbd>help</kbd> button which appears after you press the <kbd>add a comment</kbd> button(below the big black <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button)